# EF 7 beta 6 : Entities with one to many relationships in EF 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a very simple model:

```
class Bag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RandomThing> RandomThings { get; set; }
}

class RandomThing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Description{ get; set; }
}
```

My context's `OnModelCreating` (in **EF 6**) is something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Bag>()
        .ToTable("Bag")
        .HasMany(x => x.RandomThings).WithRequired(x => x.Bag).WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<RandomThing>().ToTable("RandomThing");
}
```

As far as I can tell, there is no equivalent way to do this. I know that [cascade deletes are not supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/07/27/ef7-beta-6-available.aspx). However, I was wondering, what is the best way to model the one to many relationships as defined in my code example? It seems like all of that stuff has gone (or is yet to be implemented).

I have seen an example ([here](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html)) of a `DbContext` exactly like how I want, but it's actually wrong and doesn't work. If I try to pull down that source code, set up my environment, and do a save on a blog entity with posts, those posts don't get saved as one might imagine.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: This answer was written for EF7 beta7. APIs have since changed. See http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html for the latest on using EF Core.

**Original Answer**

In EF 7, you can configure one to many relationships in the OnModelCreating method. For this to work, add a property to RandomThing to represent the forign key, and also a CLR reference to the parent type.

```
class Bag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RandomThing> RandomThings { get; set; }
}

class RandomThing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Description{ get; set; }

    public Bag Bag { get; set; }
    public int BagId { get; set; }
}
```

In your context, configure the relationship with the following setup:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{  
    modelBuilder.Entity<RandomThing>()
        .Reference(e => e.Bag)
        .InverseCollection(p => p.RandomThings)
        .ForeignKey(e => e.BagId);
}
```

*Side note*: When EF 7 [plans to add support](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/2797) for configuring this via attributes instead.

Comment: when I do a context.Add(bag) followed by a context.Save(), only the Bag entity is saved (just the Id) the RandomThings collection does not get saved accordingly.

Comment: Currently in EF 7, you need to call .Add() for reach RandomThings too, but this will likely change in upcoming betas (welcome to the joy of pre-release software).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was doing that already, I was just wondering if there was a more complete way of doing it so far.

Comment: You can follow changes to .Add() here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2726

Comment: In EF6, a specific definition was not required in OnModelCreating, but was instead inferred by certain conventions in the naming of the model properties. (e.g. BagId => Bag) Is this going to be supported some time in the future?

Comment: @natemcmaster I take it that the model builder syntax has changed to:     modelBuilder.Entity<RandomThing>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Bag)
        .WithMany(p => p.RandomThings)
        .ForeignKey(e => e.BagId);

Comment: Possibly changed again to:
modelBuilder.Entity<RandomThing>() .HasOne(e => e.Bag) .WithMany(p => p.RandomThings).HasForeignKey(e => e.BagId);

Comment: Yes, the original answer was written for pre-release APIs. They have since changed. See http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html for the latest APIs

Answer (score 0):

although I haven't used EF7 at all, in EF6 I would make your models look like this:

```
class Bag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RandomThing> RandomThings { get; set; }
}

class RandomThing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Description{ get; set; }

    public int BagId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("BagId")]
    Public Bag Bag {get; set;}
}
```

this way the relationship is taken care of with data annotations and you don't need the `model builder` for this specific task

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work yet in EF7 but support will be coming.